# Protecting a statistics endpoint

Tags: encryption, authentication

When we download an application - it asks us whether it's ok to submit statistics, error reports to the vendor. Since this data is sent from the application to server endpoint - I am wondering how authentication works in this scenario. Is this based on a certificate that resides in the application or some agreed encryption key?

Comment: Why would authentication need to work?

Comment: Otherwise unauthorized applications can feed data to that endpoint

Comment: I'm not sure why the devs would care. The data would have to be properly formed to be relevant. Unless there was an identified risk that manufactured data was going to taint their debug data, there might not be any authentication at all.

Comment: The application is sending anonymous data - if somebody sends fake data (metrics for example) it would give a wrong understanding right?

Comment: Correct. But what benefit would there be for someone to do that? The person doing that would have to understand the correct data format and value ranges, then craft and send fake data. Why would someone go through the effort?

Comment: Let's take an example - I am collecting data about an application such as CPU usage, crash reports etc. Someone who wants sabotage my analysis of this (competitor maybe) would send a bunch of fake data. I will not be able to figure out which data legitimate.

Comment: I understand the flaw, but even if a competitor decided to do this, and tries to skew data in a certain direction, aren't you going to verify problems that you see and then determine that the data is flawed? I simply don't see a viable threat here that would require authentication. Encryption? Sure. Authentication? No.

Comment: Agreed. For the encryption - I guess symmetric encryption will have to be used. I have heard about mutual SSL. Is this possible for this scenario?

Answer (score 1):

It's highly unlikely that this is a significant component of the threat model for most error reporting systems.  It's generally going to be too hard to craft fake data that will both appear to be real data to the system, and achieve some arbitrary malicious goal to boot.  It would be a lot of work for a dubious gain.

That said, there are ways you can potentially limit the impact of bad data.  For instance, you can include software registration serial numbers with the reports.   You then throw out reports that come from invalid sources (data that contains serial numbers that aren't registered to customers) or eliminate all of the data sent with a given serial number if you're getting excessive or known bad data in reports with that serial number.

So, the risk (and impact) can be limited, but it's generally not going to be worth the effort to mitigate in the first place.